how can we control the logic behind ethersJs fallbackProvider's choices
I am trying to use ethersJs to handle multiple RPCs with a fallback mechanism, to ensure we always get a response. I tried the FallbackProvider .
The probelm with it is that event if you set a quorum of 1 and give each RPC the weight of 1, the provider will still call every RPC at the same time which creates so many outgoing requests and can trigger a 429 error on multiple RPCs at the same time whcih is counter intuitive to the initial purpose of high availability.
If i am not wrong, is there a way of telling the provider to not trigger all teh PRCs at the same time ? but only until the qurorum (based on each RPC weight) is full ? Or is there another provider option ?

Dev Advocate at Chainstack here.
I made a tutorial about using the FallbackProvider. You can find it here:
Ethers.js: Enhancing blockchain data reliability with FallbackProvider
The TL;DR is that the ethers FallbackProvider is designed to work as you are experiencing; it sends the same request to multiple endpoints and returns the data based on a consensus. This is made to ensure data integrity coming from different providers, and also some redundancy, but data integrity is the main target.
So how you should use it is with endpoints from different providers. If you want a pure failsafe feature, you'll have to implement it yourself. For example, a simple load balancer kind of feature to cycle through various endpoints. I made a tutorial for this use case as well:
Make your DApp more reliable with Chainstack
This is the code example using ethers.js. Populate the endpoints in this array:
// Initialize RPC nodes from environment variables
const RPC_NODES = {
  ethersVirginia: process.env.VIRGINIA_RPC,
  ethersLondon: process.env.LONDON_RPC,
  ethersSingapore: process.env.SINGAPORE_RPC,
};

Full code:
const ethers = require('ethers');
require('dotenv').config();

// Initialize RPC nodes from environment variables
const RPC_NODES = {
  ethersVirginia: process.env.VIRGINIA_RPC,
  ethersLondon: process.env.LONDON_RPC,
  ethersSingapore: process.env.SINGAPORE_RPC,
};

// Create ethers providers for each RPC URL
const providers = {};
for (const [key, url] of Object.entries(RPC_NODES)) {
  providers[key] = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(url);
}

// Keys to cycle through providers
const keys = Object.keys(providers);
let counter = 0; // Counter to keep track of the current provider

// Function to get the latest block using the current provider
const getBlock = async () => {
  const key = keys[counter];
  const provider = providers[key];
  console.log(`Using ${key} RPC`);

  console.time("getBlock"); // Start timing the operation
  try {
    // Fetch the latest block information
    const blockByNumber = await provider.send("eth_getBlockByNumber", ["latest", false]);
        // Extract some fields to keep the response cleaner
        const blockSummary = {
          blockNumber: blockByNumber.number,
          blockHash: blockByNumber.hash,
          parentHash: blockByNumber.parentHash,
          size: blockByNumber.size,
        };
    console.log(blockSummary);
  } catch (error) {
    // If there's an error, log it and move to the next provider
    console.error(`Error fetching block: ${error.message}`);
    counter = (counter + 1) % keys.length; // Increment and wrap the counter if necessary
    console.log("Retrying request on next RPC...");
    return getBlock(); // Retry with the next provider
  }
  console.timeEnd("getBlock"); // End timing the operation

  counter = (counter + 1) % keys.length; // Move to the next provider for the next call
};

// Start the process and call getBlock every 10 seconds
console.log("Running load-balanced script with ethers.js...");
setInterval(getBlock, 2000);

In this tutorial, we are trying to create a basic load balancer. In this case, we'll use multiple Chainstack regional elastic nodes and alternate them between requests to spread the load between them. This acts as a failsafe: if one endpoint times out, the code will switch to the next one in the list.
You can find more details in the tutorial:
Make your DApp more reliable with Chainstack
